# Check on login page to enable / disable users

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have defined one column (IsEnabled) in my database table AspNetUsers on which I want to enable/disable users to login in on my login page.

The code in my Account controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
string viewName = String.Empty;


try
{

var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);


if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
{
if (model.IsEnabled == 0)
{
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(); stavime.
ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.UnableToLoginText);
}
else {

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
}
else
{
ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.UnableToLoginText);
}
}
catch {
//ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.UnableToLoginText);
}

return View(_ViewForLogin);
}
```

In my LoginViewModel I have:

```
  public class LoginViewModel
{
//[Required]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "User Name")]
[EmailAddress]
public string UserName { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Rembember Me")]
public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "IsEnabled")]
public int IsEnabled { get; set; }

}
```

The problem is that I can not read IsEnabled value form database (The value is always 0) and because that my check does not work?!

Comment: How about if you add 'if check' after successful login, retrieve your AspNetUsers  table record and then check IsEnabled field from there.

Comment: The problem is that I use SignInManager who use LoginViewModel. Because that I need somehow to use my AspNetUsers table to retrieve isEnabled value for particular user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that isEnabled will always be set to 0. Why is that?... it's because you have not looked up the value in the database. You have got the value from the form post.

```
 if (model.IsEnabled == 0)
```

Strait from the model parameter which come through on the initial post here

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<ActionResult>      Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

Can you see that? The model.IsEnabled value will always be posted with an unrelated value when the log in form is posted.

What you need to do is a DB query after the user has logged in. I think it is good to do that after the user has logged in as you have it to prevemt the db check on random unautherized email address submitted on the login form.

So insteaD make an instance of you db context do an entity framework look up on the newly logged in user and go from there.

```
 if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
 {
      object id = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey

       using(yourdbcontext db = new yourdbcontext())
      {    
      if (db.AspNetUsers.find(id).IsEnabled ==0)
       //....
       }
```

P.s. im typing on a phone

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    string viewName = String.Empty;

    AspNetUser aspmodel = new AspNetUser();



    try
    {

            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);


        if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            TryUpdateModel(aspmodel, "", new string[] { "Id", "IsEnabled" });
            if (aspmodel.IsEnabled == 0)  
            {
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(); //toj del vidi go kako go pravi I nekoj message ke stavime. 
                ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.UnableToLoginText); 
            }
            else {
            //vo HOME ke odredi vo zavisnot od koj role 
            //Applicant da go nosi vo HES 
            //Student da go nosi vo SIS 
            //Officer da go nosi vo MAIN Layout pa od tamu da bira
            //Donor da go nosi vo SIS
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.UnableToLoginText); 
        }
    }
    catch {
        //ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.UnableToLoginText);
    }

    return View(_ViewForLogin);
}
```

So, I make an new instance aspmodel for my AspNetusers:

```
 AspNetUser aspmodel = new AspNetUser();
```

and whit

```
            TryUpdateModel(aspmodel, "", new string[] { "Id", "IsEnabled" });
```

try to get IsEnabled value from database. Still does not work (I can not retrieve data from AspNetUsers table)?!

Finally works!! I added this line to ger the IsEnabled value based on the UserName:

```
ApplicationUser usr = IdentityHelper.GetUser(model.UserName);
```